# set height to fit to the container area

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup:

```css
.layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.appbar {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.drawer-container {
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
}

.drawer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #272b34;
    color: lightgray;
    border-style: none;
    align-self: stretch;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.drawer-content {
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    margin-top: 1px;
    align-self: stretch;
    background-color: #eef5f9;
    overflow: auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.component {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.header {
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.grid-container {
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
  height: calc(100% - 82px);
  background-color: red;
}

.grid {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid-content {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout" class="layout">
  <div id="appbar" class="appbar">
    APPBAR
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
    <div id="drawercontainer" class="drawer-container">
      <div id="drawer" class="drawer">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
          <li>item 4</li>
          <li>item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="drawercontent" class="drawer-content">
        <div id="component" class="component">
          <div class="header">HEADER</div>
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid">
              <div class="grid-content">GRID CONTENT</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is about this piece of css:

```
.grid-container {
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
  height: calc(100% - 82px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

Setting the height like this, I can avoid, that the `component` element has a scrollbar. It means, the `grid-container` and the `header` have a total height of the `component`. But if I test it with different screen size / pixel ratio, I get a scrollbar (with little scrolling). Note, that the `component` has to have the property `overflow` set.

The question is, how can I avoid to set the height this way? How can I avoid the use of pixels or any other units? Basically, I want that the `grid-container` fills always the remaining area from the `component` element on any screen sizes / resolutions, without showing any scrollbar, it means not extending it.

Comment: Well you have a 500px height element inside a container with overflow: auto...

Comment: You have to either have smaller grid-content, or scrolling/hidden/visible overflow of grid-content. If I'm not understanding can you edit the question to clarify a bit.

Comment: But please note, I'm limiting the height of the grid-container. So, the grid-content itself can be any size, because the grid itself has overflow: auto. The grid-container should have always a size = header + grid container (not the grid itself). In the example, it does have exactly the size, but I can achieve this only by setting the height like described (with substracting a fix value).

Comment: Ok I'll take another look, are you using `* { box-sizing: border-box } ` to make sure padding is included in the height calcs?

Comment: You have margin too, so maybe box sizing of margin-box or removing the margin should fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this snippet does what you want:

- Sane default of `box-sizing: border-box` on every element
- Removed stupid margin on the body which caused pagewide scrollbar on 100vh height
- Swapped margin on grid-container for padding
- Tidied up some shorthands etc. `padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem` -> `padding: 1rem` are the same

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.appbar {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.drawer-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.drawer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #272b34;
  color: lightgray;
  border-style: none;
  align-self: stretch;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.drawer-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1px;
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: #eef5f9;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.component {
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.grid-container {
  padding: 1rem;
  height: calc(100% - 82px);
}

.grid {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid-content {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout" class="layout">
  <div id="appbar" class="appbar">
    APPBAR
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
    <div id="drawercontainer" class="drawer-container">
      <div id="drawer" class="drawer">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
          <li>item 4</li>
          <li>item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="drawercontent" class="drawer-content">
        <div id="component" class="component">
          <div class="header">HEADER</div>
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid">
              <div class="grid-content">GRID CONTENT</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn that scrollbar is messed up, doesn't even show up in FireFox

Comment: I had to test it at work too. It works. Thanks.